# Check on a VPS Server for an update on a git repository

Tags: git, github, vps

I want to have my server running a git pull to update the files inside the server at a determined interval, meanwhile I edit them and push them into the repository.
For example, if I edit a file in my computer, push it to git and the VPS will be running every 5 seconds (for example) a check for an update on the repository, so then when it checks that it will replace the files with the correct ones.

Comment: This is a perfect use of a cron job.

Comment: I made this but it sends me an email every time it tries saying that doesn't have permission. Why?

`*/1 * * * * /var/www/vhosts/localhost.localdomain/capitanchewbacca.com -c 'git pull'`

Answer (score 0):

Git hooks exist for this reason.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

You would ideally use a hook to notify a web server or some local script that work should be performed.

Comment: Thanks tencent. But there is any script already made for that? Or can someone make one?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't exist for people to ask other people to make something for them. You need to hire someone in that situation if you are unwilling to figure it out.